# Yii2 : Active Record Column Aliases

Tags: activerecord, alias, yii2

I'm using Yii2 framework with advanced template.

I get problem with column alias in my controller file, here's my code:

```
$models = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => User::find()->select(['member'=>'fullname'])
]);
```

The above query equivalent with:

```
SELECT fullname AS member FROM User;
```

I send the data to the view using this code:

```
return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $models,
    ]);
```

I want to call the data in my view using GridView widget, here's my code:

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $model,
    'columns' => [
        'member',
    ],
]);
```

However, I got an error that tell me the 'member' parameter is not defined.
How can I show the data of my query by calling the column name? (in my case it using alias)

I really appreciate any kind of helps!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should simply declare this attribute in your model :

```
class User extends ActiveRecord
{

    public $member;
```

Read more : https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#selecting-extra-fields

Comment: well this works, thank you very much.

I try to add 'member' in function rules before, never thought about make it as public variable

Comment: it need proper explanation to help people in future

Answer (score 5):

[ActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-activedataprovider.html) works only with model attributes. `member` obviously is not presented there.

First of all, maybe it's better to refactor column names to be more clear instead of writing aliases? I don't see any benefit in your example.

If you nevertheless need to use aliases, as alternative for adding additional properties to class, you can work with them with help of [ArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html) and [SqlDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sqldataprovider.html).

Examples of usage:

**ArrayDataProvider:**

```
use yii\data\ArrayDataProvider;

$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => User::find()->select(['member' => 'fullname'])->all(),
]);
```

**SqlDataProvider:**

```
use yii\data\SqlDataProvider;
use yii\db\Query;

...

$query = (new Query())
    ->select(['member' => 'fullname'])
    ->from('users');

$command = $query->createCommand();

$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
    'sql' => $command->sql,
    'params' => $command->params,
    'totalCount' => $query->count(),
]);
```

For more details and features of usage please see official docs.

For your case it's better to use `ArrayDataProvider`, `SqlDataProvider` is for more complex queries.

In case of one alias and using model methods adding additional attribute as suggested by **soju** can be better.

But in my opinion it's useless and it's better to refactor column names in case of some ambiguity.

Comment: the reason I use aliases because my query using more sql command.

it something like this:
SELECT EXTRACT(month from time) AS MonthS FROM user

in my opinion aliases just solve that, but thank you for your explanation about SqlDataProvider..next time I'll use it as well :)

Comment: You better mention such details in question. Using `SqlDataProvider` can be better then.