# Yii2 Filter Calculated Field from a Case Statement

Tags: yii2, query-builder

I have been trying to get a filter on a calculated case statement column in Yii 2 this is what I have in the search model:

```
    $query = Pricing::find();
    $query->select("*, (CASE WHEN MyPrice > CompetitorPrice THEN 'Higher' WHEN MyPrice = CompetitorPrice THEN  'Equal' ELSE  'Lower' END) AS standing");      

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,

    ]);
    //Added Sorting to Calculated Field
    $dataProvider->setSort([
        'attributes' => [
            'standing' => [
            'asc' => ['standing' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['standing' => SORT_DESC],
            'label' => 'Standing',
          ],
        ]
    ]);
```

and I added this below

`$query->andFilterWhere(['Standing' => $this->standing]);`

But when I try and search against the filter I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Standing' in 'where clause'
>   The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Pricing` WHERE `Standing`='Lower'

Why is the filter trying to get the count from the plain table without the case statement? And how can I fix this so I can get the filter to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you're using this query in a `gridView` or similar. Yii always does a `count` query first, so that it can set the appropriate pagination for the view.

The [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#select) suggests using an array if any of your `select` query has commas, so it may be worth trying that, like this. You also need to [specify the sort differently](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sort.html);

```
    $dataProvider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Pricing::find()->select([
            '*',
            'standing' => '(CASE WHEN MyPrice > CompetitorPrice THEN 'Higher' WHEN MyPrice = CompetitorPrice THEN  'Equal' ELSE  'Lower' END)'
        ]),
        'sort' => [
            'attributes' => [
                'standing' => [
                    'asc' => ['standing' => SORT_ASC],
                    'desc' => ['standing' => SORT_DESC],
                    'default' => SORT_DESC,
                    'label' => 'Standing'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273727/yii2-active-record-column-aliases) answer, you also have to declare your alias as a public variable in your model. That should sort it for you.

```
public $standing;
```

Comment: Yes, I am using gridview.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but it didnt work :(.

I am using gridview.

I tried your query but the Case statement wont work without the parentheses so I changed it to this:

`$query->select(["*", "(CASE WHEN MyPrice > CompetitorPrice THEN 'Higher' WHEN MyPrice = CompetitorPrice THEN  'Equal' ELSE  'Lower' END) AS standing"]);`

But, it still tries to get the count of a non-existant field, any ideas how I can get the count to work with the calculated field?

Comment: I tried this because it would not work without _END_ `$query->select(["*", "standing" => "(CASE WHEN MyPrice > CompetitorPrice THEN 'Higher' WHEN MyPrice = CompetitorPrice THEN  'Equal' ELSE  'Lower' END)"]);` , but it still comes back with _Unknown column 'Standing' in 'where clause'_ error @Joe Miller, I should mention that everything else works except the filter which is where I am running into the Unknown column error

Comment: @imos I think I've cracked it, see the bottom of my amended answer.

Comment: I already had `public $standing;` in my model :), The data displays correctly, the only issue is the filter. I think my issue has to do with what you originally said _Yii always does a count query first_, the problem is that the count query runs before the select query, so the case statement that adds the new column doesnt exist at the time of the count. @Joe Miller

Comment: Added a different way of specifying sort order. I've tested this and it should work :-) @imos

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99043/discussion-between-joe-miller-and-imos).

Comment: So the last part of this was to get the filter to work all I needed to do was add my field without using the alias as Standing and now it is filterable :) _$query->andFilterWhere(["(CASE WHEN MyPrice > CompetitorPrice THEN 'Higher' WHEN MyPrice = CompetitorPrice THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'Lower' END)" => $this->standing]);_